# What kind of og:type should be in grapth facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use sharing function in Facebook. When I try to debug my meta tags I get error:

```
Object is invalid because the configured 'og:type' of 'social network' is invalid.
```

I use string value for `'og:type`:

```
"Social Network"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This object is not included in the facebook object library, you have to first create the object 'social.media' by  clicking Add Object Type in the Object Types section of your App Dashboard.

Comment: Do you mean I must to create all types in Facebook Dev?

Comment: As a general principle you should use the built-in objects and actions if possible. But there is a possibility to create new ones as well. You can read more about it here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph

Answer (score 1):

You can find all availables types for Open Graph types on this page: http://ogp.me/

...or here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph#object-type

The most common one is "website". If it´s not in the list, you have to create it on your own: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/[your-app-id]/open-graph/